# Bottling/Corking

Tags: bottling

Here is the run down: I have a 6 gallon batch of pinot grigio that I have fermenting and a 6 gallon batch of summer saison that is also nearing completion.  I am looking to upgrade my bottling process for beer and I also need to buy a corker for my wine.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what corker/capper to buy? Is going with a dual purpose topper a good idea? Any input would be GREATLY appreciated, much of the amazon toppers don't have many reviews, aside from the handheld cappers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wife and I just order this [floor corker](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/portuguese-floor-corker.html) from Northern Brewer.

We'll be corking up some Australian Shiraz.  I plan to use it for some high gravity Belgians I brew up occasionally too.

Comment: I have looked at these but i have not heard what ppl say about them.  Let me know if that one works well and better yet if it can be used as a bottle capper as well.

Comment: I bought this one because I saw plenty of reviews that it was good.  And I saw it in action at my LHBS.  Its the corker that most people upgrade to from the cheaper starter corkers most new wine bottlers get.

Comment: I recently bought this one as well to cork our first wine, I will check back to let everyone know how it works.

Comment: To follow this up, I received my corker and it was a biggin'!  We also bottled with it this passed weekend...  I don't know how or why anyone would use anything BUT a floor corker. +1 for that product.  I know this didn't necessarily answer the beer capper question but the corker for sure is useful!